# What is the correct way of citing a book in a presentation (made using Beamer)

Tags: citations, mathematics, presentation

I am making slides for presentation using beamer.

I have the following reference book in the bibliography in the following format

> [5]Author 1 and Author 2, *book name*, publication house, year

I have to refer many theorems in the above book, so how should I include page number or in the presentation should I cite like this

> Theorem 1 [5]  :  "theorem statement"

Or do I need to include the names of authors while citing along with page numbers?

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: In a presentation people can’t click on a citation to see what it’s referring to. You should include the names of the authors on the same slide (at least the first time you mention the book if you’re mentioning it many times) since that’s the only thing your audience will be seeing during your talk.

Comment: @DanRomik That looks like an answer ;-)

Comment: @Dan Romik It will be nice if you post it as an answer otherwise the question will remain simply in the unanswered list.